# NameError: name 'nn' is not defined

Tags: pytorch

Several times when I copy PyTorch code I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'nn' is not defined
```

What is missing? What is `nn`?

---

<sub>To reproduce:</sub>

```
class SLL(nn.Module):
    "single linear layer"
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(10,100)        

    def forward(self)->None: 
        print("SLL:forward")

m1 = SLL()
```

Comment: Can you supply a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure @MilkyWay90, will add how to reproduce.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you got this error you can fix it with the following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
```

You need to include both lines, since if you set just the second one it may not work if the `torch` package is not imported.

Where [`torch`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html) and [`torch.nn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) (or just `nn`) are two of the main PyTorch packages. You can `help(torch.nn)` to confirm this.

It is not uncommon when you include `nn` to include the functional interface as `F` like this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
```

To bring you the hints what you imported or what is inside the `nn` package I provided the list:

```
['AdaptiveAvgPool1d', 'AdaptiveAvgPool2d', 'AdaptiveAvgPool3d', 'AdaptiveLogSoftmaxWithLoss', 'AdaptiveMaxPool1d', 'AdaptiveMaxPool2d', 'AdaptiveMaxPool3d', 'AlphaDropout', 'AvgPool1d', 'AvgPool2d', 'AvgPool3d', 'BCELoss', 'BCEWithLogitsLoss', 'BatchNorm1d', 'BatchNorm2d', 'BatchNorm3d', 'Bilinear', 'CELU', 'CTCLoss', 'ConstantPad1d', 'ConstantPad2d', 'ConstantPad3d', 'Container', 'Conv1d', 'Conv2d', 'Conv3d', 'ConvTranspose1d', 'ConvTranspose2d', 'ConvTranspose3d', 'CosineEmbeddingLoss', 'CosineSimilarity', 'CrossEntropyLoss', 'CrossMapLRN2d', 'DataParallel', 'Dropout', 'Dropout2d', 'Dropout3d', 'ELU', 'Embedding', 'EmbeddingBag', 'FeatureAlphaDropout', 'Fold', 'FractionalMaxPool2d', 'GLU', 'GRU', 'GRUCell', 'GroupNorm', 'Hardshrink', 'Hardtanh', 'HingeEmbeddingLoss', 'InstanceNorm1d', 'InstanceNorm2d', 'InstanceNorm3d', 'KLDivLoss', 'L1Loss', 'LPPool1d', 'LPPool2d', 'LSTM', 'LSTMCell', 'LayerNorm', 'LeakyReLU', 'Linear', 'LocalResponseNorm', 'LogSigmoid', 'LogSoftmax', 'MSELoss', 'MarginRankingLoss', 'MaxPool1d', 'MaxPool2d', 'MaxPool3d', 'MaxUnpool1d', 'MaxUnpool2d', 'MaxUnpool3d', 'Module', 'ModuleDict', 'ModuleList', 'MultiLabelMarginLoss', 'MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss', 'MultiMarginLoss', 'NLLLoss', 'NLLLoss2d', 'PReLU', 'PairwiseDistance', 'Parameter', 'ParameterDict', 'ParameterList', 'PixelShuffle', 'PoissonNLLLoss', 'RNN', 'RNNBase', 'RNNCell', 'RNNCellBase', 'RReLU', 'ReLU', 'ReLU6', 'ReflectionPad1d', 'ReflectionPad2d', 'ReplicationPad1d', 'ReplicationPad2d', 'ReplicationPad3d', 'SELU', 'Sequential', 'Sigmoid', 'SmoothL1Loss', 'SoftMarginLoss', 'Softmax', 'Softmax2d', 'Softmin', 'Softplus', 'Softshrink', 'Softsign', 'Tanh', 'Tanhshrink', 'Threshold', 'TripletMarginLoss', 'Unfold', 'Upsample', 'UpsamplingBilinear2d', 'UpsamplingNearest2d', 'ZeroPad2d', '_VF', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_functions', '_reduction', 'backends', 'functional', 'grad', 'init', 'modules', 'parallel', 'parameter', 'utils']
```

Containing many classes where probable the most fundamental one is the PyTorch class `nn.Module`.

<sub>Do not confuse PyTorch class [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module) with the Python modules.</sub>

---

To fix the `SLL` model from the question you just have to add the first two lines:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SLL(nn.Module):
    "single linear layer"
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(10,100)        

    def forward(self)->None: 
        print("SLL:forward")

# we create a module instance m1
m1 = SLL()
```

And you will get the output:

```
SLL(
  (l1): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=100, bias=True)
)
```